# How to use my router's Mac Address on Pfsense installed on Esxi

Tags: pfsense, mac-address, spoofing

My ISP bind my router's Mac address so only this router can connect to their pppoe server, now I want to connect it on Pfsense installed on Esxi for better configuration options but pppoe server is not connecting on pfSense probably because of Mac Binding.

- Let's say my router's Mac is `aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa`
- My server nic Mac is `bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb`
- pfSence VM adapter is `E1000e` and Mac is set to `Automatic` (I've also tried to set `aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa` but it didn't work).
- pfSense Wan's interface left blank (also tried with `aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa` but no luck pppoe server won't connect).

Is this even possible what I'm trying to achieve?

I've also tried to set VM adapter's mac and pfSense Wan's interface to `aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa` at the same time but still it didn't work

PS: I know I can connect pppoe server on router and than use one the Lan port as pfSense's Wan port but I don't want to use it like that for specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bridged networking for your pfsense VM? If so, I think, the problem is, that the physical mac of your server's NIC is bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb and the pfsense interface with aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa comes behind the server's interface. Many ISP's are allowing the correct MAC only, if it is the first interface connected.

I don't know, if you can do this with esxi but if your server has more than one NICs, I would try to attach one of the physical NICs directly to the pfsense VM and set the aa MAC on the interface.

Comment: Yes I have one built-in 1gbe and a quard 1gbe nic. Are you talking about Pci pass-through?